# Does turn undead gain the benefits from a Sacred Mask?

Tags: dnd-4e

Sacred Mask

> When you use a Channel Divinity class feature, until the end of your next turn, you deal 1d6 extra radiant damage against undead enemies and can score a critical hit against undead enemies on a roll of 18–20.

If the wearer of the mask uses Turn Undead (a Channel Divinity class feature), do the bonuses conferred by the Sacred Mask apply to that attack? Or do the bonuses only kick in after the Channel Divinity is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the benefits apply for that attack and any other attacks until the end of your next turn.